# Perl submit to a page, then submit again

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
$IEDocument = $IE->{Document};
$Forms = $IEDocument->all;
$form = $forms->item{'search');
$form->click;

# it clicks the search button which submits to a page
# then I do the following

$doc = $IE->{Document}; #Not sure if correct
$forms = $doc->{DocumentElement}->{InnerHTML};
$form = $forms->item('field');
$form->{value} = "12345";

# The following code must submit to a page, then put new info in an input field on that new submitted page
```

But it doesn't work, whats a way to do this? I researched so much, someone suggested to use WWW::Mechanize, but when I use it I can't take screenshot of the page, because the Mechanize just shows whats its doing in CMD, and doesn't really open a browser. (BTW is there a way to open a browser with WWW::Mechanize and see whats actually going on?)

Comment: why do you need a screenshot?

Comment: I need a picture from a page that it submits to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give some **details** about how it

> doesn't work

To take screenshots you can use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox module:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get('http://google.com');

my $png = $mech->content_as_png(); #you have a screen in $png now
```

Comment: This is really nice, but I want certain part of the screen and not the whole screen. Is this also possible with WWW::Mechanize? Also to install` WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` do I do `cpan WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`

Comment: Also, does this open a browser and do whatever you do? Or it does it in CMD (Not that good with the terms)

Comment: Sorry, by "screen" I mean only target site screenshot. What you mean by "certain part"? Also you need `cpan install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`. After installation you need to make some tweaks to your Firefox (install Mozrepl plugin)

Comment: lets say I want to screenshot 300x300 pixel starting from 100x100 coordinates

Comment: gangabass, that's just [`cpan`](http://p3rl.org/cpan), not [`cpan install`](http://p3rl.org/install).

Comment: Grigor, it helps to [read the documentation](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#IMAGE-METHODS) of the software you're working with.

Comment: I also pasted your code and got the following response: `Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: No connecti
on could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at C:/strawberr
y/perl/site/lib/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144`

Comment: @daxim I take it back, I read the documentation of the module in a different place and I think I missed the part about coordinates, thanks for the link!